# New Column based on Group and Condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create new column based on the `SOURCE` column value for distinct `ID`.
There are multiple records for same IDs with different or same Name as there source are different. I am trying to create new column `CNAME` to standardize the Name for each ID based on `SOURCE` column value.

For each `ID`, `CNAME` column should be equal to the `NAME` where `SOURCE` == `A`

df:

```
ID  NAME    SOURCE
1   ABC     B
1   ABC     C
1   AXY     A
2   XYZ     B
2   XYZ     A
3   SASA    D
3   SASA    B
3   SSA     A
3   SSA     C
4   BVA     A
4   BA      B
5   NAS     A
5   VAN     B
```

Output:

```
ID  NAME    SOURCE  CNAME
1   ABC     B       AXY
1   ABC     C       AXY
1   AXY     A       AXY
2   XYZ     B       XYZ
2   XYZ     A       XYZ
3   SASA    D       SSA
3   SASA    B       SSA
3   SSA     A       SSA
3   SSA     C       SSA
4   BVA     A       BVA
4   BA      B       BVA
5   NAS     A       NAS
5   VAN     B       NAS
```

After grouping, i am not able to understand how to fill back value to new column for all rows. I tried to make use of `transform` as well but no luck.

```
df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: np.where(x['SOURCE'] == 'A', x['NAME'],' '))
```

Comment: "4:BA:B" is a typo? Isn't it "BVA"?

Comment: Its not a Typo. Name could be different since source is different. So to standardize that i am trying to create new column where correct Name is present in Source A.

Comment: Excellent. Check my answer then ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sort_values, groupby ID and broadcast the first SOURCE in each group using transform

```
df['CNAME'] = df.sort_values(by=['ID','SOURCE']).groupby('ID')['NAME'].transform('first')
```

Following your clarifying question you can;

```
s=df.query("SOURCE=='A'")#Filter all the A now that they are not repeated

df['CNAME'] = df['ID'].map(dict(zip(s['ID'],s['NAME'])))#create dict and map


     ID  NAME SOURCE CNAME
0    1   ABC      B   AXY
1    1   ABC      C   AXY
2    1   AXY      A   AXY
3    2   XYZ      B   XYZ
4    2   XYZ      A   XYZ
5    3  SASA      D   SSA
6    3  SASA      B   SSA
7    3   SSA      A   SSA
8    3   SSA      C   SSA
9    4   BVA      A   BVA
10   4    BA      B   BVA
11   5   NAS      A   NAS
12   5   VAN      B   NAS
```

Comment: Is there any ways to do it by matching the value of Source ? Above is dummy data. How would i do it if i need to match it to `C`

Comment: Yes you can map as weell. Please see my edit as requested

Answer (score 0):

This is a little "sql-ish" (creating a lookup table if you will, then using it in a join or merge operation) but also works:

```
# get the list of CNAME ids
ids = df[df.SOURCE == 'A']

# join/merge the two dataframes
new_df = df.merge(ids, on='ID', how='left')

# capture the new columns from the joined dataframe
new_df = new_df[['ID', 'NAME_x', 'SOURCE_x', 'NAME_y']]

# rename the columns
new_df.columns = ['ID', 'NAME', 'SOURCE', 'CNAME']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the proper way of doing it... but it works when you want to select a custom item, like `SOURCE B` in this case

```
mapper = df[df['SOURCE']=='B'].set_index('ID')['NAME']
mapper.name = 'NEWID'
df.merge(mapper, on='ID')

    ID  NAME SOURCE NEWID
0    1   ABC      B   ABC
1    1   ABC      C   ABC
2    1   AXY      A   ABC
3    2   XYZ      B   XYZ
4    2   XYZ      A   XYZ
5    3  SASA      D  SASA
6    3  SASA      B  SASA
7    3   SSA      A  SASA
8    3   SSA      C  SASA
9    4   BVA      A    BA
10   4    BA      B    BA
11   5   NAS      A   VAN
12   5   VAN      B   VAN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['ID','SOURCE'])
df.loc[df['SOURCE'] == 'A','CNAME'] = df.NAME
df.CNAME = df['CNAME'].ffill()
df
```

| index | ID | NAME | SOURCE | CNAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | AXY | A | AXY |
| 0 | 1 | ABC | B | AXY |
| 1 | 1 | ABC | C | AXY |
| 4 | 2 | XYZ | A | XYZ |
| 3 | 2 | XYZ | B | XYZ |
| 7 | 3 | SSA | A | SSA |
| 6 | 3 | SASA | B | SSA |
| 8 | 3 | SSA | C | SSA |
| 5 | 3 | SASA | D | SSA |
| 9 | 4 | BVA | A | BVA |
| 10 | 4 | BA | B | BVA |
| 11 | 5 | NAS | A | NAS |
| 12 | 5 | VAN | B | NAS |